# Crontab jobs does not run any script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

It is not my first time to use crontab but it is my first time on new VPS.
I made a test to for example send a message to my telegram like this:

`echo "Hii"|notify`

and saved it as  ss.sh
when I run it, it works without any problems.
but when I make a crontab command like this:

> */2  * * * *  /bin/sh /root/ss.sh

it does not work. I am sure of the right path which is /root/ss.sh and the ss.sh is excutable.
I am really do not know where is the problem I can not run any script through crontab.

Comment: How will your shell know where `notify` is if you don't set your PATH?

Comment: If you went to the trouble of making your script executable, why not add a shebang as the first line so you can actually use it like an executable instead of having to invoke the shell each time?

Comment: I installed notify using go and it is in my PATH as I just need to type notify to run it.

Comment: I do not get your second point, can you please explain more?

Comment: What does notify do? If it does something like pop a window up on your screen, then cron is not the right place for this: cron runs "headless"

Comment: But your PATH is set differently when you login, as opposed to under `cron`.

Comment: notify:https://github.com/projectdiscovery/notify

Comment: So what should I do Mark?

Comment: You can run a script called say `SCRIPT` in at least 3 ways. 1) Use `/bin/sh SCRIPT` and it is not necessary to make it executable, or 2) You can make the first line of the script `#!/bin/sh` and make the script executable (with `chmod `) and invoke it with `./SCRIPT` 3) As per 2, but add `.` to your `PATH` and invoke with `SCRIPT`.

Comment: Add a shebang as the first line `#!/bin/sh`. Set your `PATH` on the second line `export PATH=$PATH:/DIRECTORY/CONTAINING/NOTIFY` Find where `notify` lives using `type notify` in your regular Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should:
check the execution of logs in /var/log/cron

```
cat /var/log/cron | grep ss.sh
```

check the cron as root user in

```
crontab-l
```

if it is not there then add it with

```
crontab -e
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh/ root/ss.sh
```

Then check the service status

```
systemctl status crond.service
```

Reload the service

```
systemctl reload crond.service
```